# AWS S3 Allows to create bucket name Caps through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

When you provide S3 bucket name as Capital letters using Console - it throws error (Caps letters not allowed)

However, when you create the bucket in S3 using CLI - it just creates.

I'm I missing any settings? Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the AWS Management Console, bucket names must be ***DNS-compliant in all Regions***.

Rule 2 of DNS compliant name states that:

> Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels
>   are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can contain
>   lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. **Each label must start and
>   end with a lowercase letter or a number**.

Hence you are NOT able to create bucket starting with *CAPITAL LETTERS* from console (*Infact console doesn't allow you to use CAPITAL LETTERS at all in the bucket-name*) but `aws_cli` allows you to create bucket name starting with caps.

The US East (N. Virginia) currently allows more relaxed standards for bucket naming.

You can check the rules in this section of S3 documentation [Rules for Bucket Naming](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html).